# How to add theme settings to Zen-based themes?

Tags: drupal, drupal-themes

I'm trying to place my own theme settings into a drupal subtheme. i've used the forms API in theme-settings.php but they are not showing up in admin/build/themes/settings/$mytheme. my theme-settings.php is uploaded [here](http://olhameucodigo.com.br/c51) in case you'd like to see it.
what it does is choose vocabularies for categories and tags, making it easier to port wordpress blogs to drupal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, the thing seems to be in mytheme.info
it seems i need to place a default value here in order to have the settings saved.
but i guess it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: and i did it through settings[something] = 0